# Can't input variable into Date constructor inside timestamp in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I want to use queries related to timestamps

Notice : setSD and setED are in the data of the Vue object, and the call firebase function is in the method.

```
callFirebase: function (){
        let startdate = new Date(this.setSD+'T00:00:00');
        let enddate = new Date(this.setED+'T00:00:00');
        console.log(startdate);
        console.log(enddate);
        db.collection("study").
        where("time", ">=", firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(startdate)).
        where("time", "<=", firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(enddate))
        .get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
                console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data().time.toDate());
            });
        })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
            });
        }
    }
```

Error image:

[image]

```
callFirebase: function (){
        let startdate = new Date(this.setSD+'T00:00:00');
        let enddate = new Date(this.setED+'T00:00:00');
        console.log(startdate);
        console.log(enddate);
        db.collection("study").
        where("time", ">=", new Date(this.setSD+'T00:00:00')).
        where("time", "<=", new Date(this.setED+'T00:00:00'))
        .get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
                console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data().time.toDate());
            });
        })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
            });
        }
    }
```

And I tried it this way, but the same problem occurred.

```
callFirebase: function (){
        let startdate = new Date(this.setSD+'T00:00:00');
        let enddate = new Date(this.setED+'T00:00:00');
        console.log(startdate);
        console.log(enddate);
        db.collection("study").
        where("time", ">=", new Date('2019-12-31T00:00:00')).
        where("time", "<=", new Date('2020-01-01T00:00:00'))
        .get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
                console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data().time.toDate());
            });
        })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
            });
        }
    }
```

But what I can't understand the most is that this runs.
My conclusion was that I couldn't use variables inside the where clause.
But after searching a little more, it doesn't seem to be that way. Can someone help me?

Comment: Could you please show some examples of value of setSD and setED?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve it myself by doing like this,

```
  callFirebase: function (){     
        let startdate = new Date(this.setSD+'T00:00:00');
        startdate.setHours(startdate.getHours()+9);
        let enddate = new Date(this.setED+'T00:00:00');
        enddate.setHours(enddate.getHours()+9);
        console.log(startdate.toISOString());
        console.log(enddate.toISOString().split('.',1)[0]);
        db.collection("study").
        where("time", ">=", new Date(startdate.toISOString().split('.',1)[0])).
        where("time", "<=", new Date(enddate.toISOString().split('.',1)[0])).
        get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
                console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data().time.toDate());
            });
        })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
            });
        }
    }
```

When declaring a `new Date()`, `date.toISOString()` is set by default in the where clause.
`(such as 2020-01-21T00:00:00.000Z)`

So I use split () to convert it to a string that fits the date constructor.